# How to parse arguments in the style of git or conda in python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

At least a few current command line tools follow the general pattern of:

```
 $> program-name action [zero or more action specific options & arguments
```

For example

```
$> git checkout -b new-branch
$> git diff HEAD HEAD~2
... and so on ...
```

The idea is that we have different actions/commands (checkcout, diff, commit etc.) and the arguments/options for each command can be different.

How do you implement this pattern in python (ideally using `argparse`)?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Answer (score 0):

(FTFM!) This is directly supported by [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)

```
   >>> # create the top-level parser
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='foo help')
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')
>>>
>>> # create the parser for the "a" command
>>> parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
>>> parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')
>>>
>>> # create the parser for the "b" command
>>> parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
>>> parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')
>>>
>>> # parse some argument lists
>>> parser.parse_args(['a', '12'])
Namespace(bar=12, foo=False)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'b', '--baz', 'Z'])
Namespace(baz='Z', foo=True)
```